# Gatsby build fails on not valid HTML tags (WebpackError)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I'm moving to Gatsby large news website (over 60.000 pages). Some migrated pages have errors in HTML, for example:

```
lorem <b, ipsum dolor sit
```

it leads to error on build:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.384s

 ERROR #95313  HTML.COMPILATION

Building static HTML failed for path "/lorem-ipsum/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  19 |
  20 |  // Split the array in 2 parts
> 21 |  var left = components.slice(0, split);
     | ^
  22 |  var right = components.slice(split);
  23 |
  24 |  return Array.prototype.concat.call([], decodeComponents(left), decodeComponents(right));

WebpackError: Invalid tag: b,
```

Obviously because there is no tag "b," (b with comma) in HTML. :)

We do not consider automatic attempts to correct the HTML code, because they can lead to unpredictable results.
I'd like to make this site reasonably bulletproof before handing it over to a client. Bulletproof, i.e. I would like to minimize the risk of error during build.

It's better that it builds with an error in the HTML code than not at all. Then the user will have a chance to correct the page code and build it again.

So is it possible to force Gatsby and Webpack to ignore these types of HTML errors?

Edit:

Error above comes from this line of code:

```
{parse(post.content)}
```

parse() is from "html-react-parser"

Answer (score -1):

Eventualy sanitizer did the trick: https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser/issues/124#issuecomment-538212031

```
import sanitizeHtml from 'sanitize-html';

const cleanPostContent = sanitizeHtml(post.content);

return (
        <>
            {parse(cleanPostContent)}
        </>
    )
```